# NAO robot remote audio problems

Tags: python, audio, nao-robot

I would like to know if anyone here knows how to stream NAO robot audio to a remote module in python, and if you maybe have an example. I want to get the NAO audio buffers on my laptop directly for processing, so no recording and scp or whatever.

Now my problem is this: the aldebaran site says that in order to receive audio remotely (on my laptop), I have to write a module that inherits from ALSoundExtractor. The thing is, this class was not included in the python SDK, so if you're building a remote python program, you CAN'T inherit from alsoundextractor... I've been stuck on this problem for weeks, and it would be really nice if someone could help me out.

so the idea is to start the module with

```
class AudioClassificationModule(ALSoundExtractor):
```

and have a function called process that is called automatically. I get this error though:

```
NameError: name 'ALSoundExtractor' is not defined
```

so it boils down to this: could someone show how this should be done?? write a python module that inherits from ALSoundExtractor, and has a function 'process' that does something with the audio? THANKS!!

documentation link: [https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/doc/1-14/naoqi/audio/alaudiodevice-api.html#ALAudioDeviceProxy::subscribe__ssCR](https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/doc/1-14/naoqi/audio/alaudiodevice-api.html#ALAudioDeviceProxy%3a%3asubscribe__ssCR)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

here's a "small" sample

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

###########################################################
# Retrieve robot audio buffer
# Syntaxe:
#    python scriptname --pip <ip> --pport <port>
# 
#    --pip <ip>: specify the ip of your robot (without specification it will use the NAO_IP defined some line below
#
# Author: Alexandre Mazel
###########################################################

NAO_IP = "10.0.252.126" # Romeo on table
#~ NAO_IP = "10.0.253.99" # Nao Alex Blue


from optparse import OptionParser
import naoqi
import numpy as np
import time
import sys


class SoundReceiverModule(naoqi.ALModule):
    """
    Use this object to get call back from the ALMemory of the naoqi world.
    Your callback needs to be a method with two parameter (variable name, value).
    """

    def __init__( self, strModuleName, strNaoIp ):
        try:
            naoqi.ALModule.__init__(self, strModuleName );
            self.BIND_PYTHON( self.getName(),"callback" );
            self.strNaoIp = strNaoIp;
            self.outfile = None;
            self.aOutfile = [None]*(4-1); # ASSUME max nbr channels = 4
        except BaseException, err:
            print( "ERR: abcdk.naoqitools.SoundReceiverModule: loading error: %s" % str(err) );

    # __init__ - end
    def __del__( self ):
        print( "INF: abcdk.SoundReceiverModule.__del__: cleaning everything" );
        self.stop();

    def start( self ):
        audio = naoqi.ALProxy( "ALAudioDevice", self.strNaoIp, 9559 );
        nNbrChannelFlag = 0; # ALL_Channels: 0,  AL::LEFTCHANNEL: 1, AL::RIGHTCHANNEL: 2; AL::FRONTCHANNEL: 3  or AL::REARCHANNEL: 4.
        nDeinterleave = 0;
        nSampleRate = 48000;
        audio.setClientPreferences( self.getName(),  nSampleRate, nNbrChannelFlag, nDeinterleave ); # setting same as default generate a bug !?!
        audio.subscribe( self.getName() );
        print( "INF: SoundReceiver: started!" );
        # self.processRemote( 4, 128, [18,0], "A"*128*4*2 ); # for local test

        # on romeo, here's the current order:
        # 0: right;  1: rear;   2: left;   3: front,  

    def stop( self ):
        print( "INF: SoundReceiver: stopping..." );
        audio = naoqi.ALProxy( "ALAudioDevice", self.strNaoIp, 9559 );
        audio.unsubscribe( self.getName() );        
        print( "INF: SoundReceiver: stopped!" );
        if( self.outfile != None ):
            self.outfile.close();


    def processRemote( self, nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel, aTimeStamp, buffer ):
        """
        This is THE method that receives all the sound buffers from the "ALAudioDevice" module
        """
        #~ print( "process!" );
        #~ print( "processRemote: %s, %s, %s, lendata: %s, data0: %s (0x%x), data1: %s (0x%x)" % (nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel, aTimeStamp, len(buffer), buffer[0],ord(buffer[0]),buffer[1],ord(buffer[1])) );
        #~ print( "raw data: " ),
        #~ for i in range( 8 ):
            #~ print( "%s (0x%x), " % (buffer[i],ord(buffer[i])) ),
        #~ print( "" );

        aSoundDataInterlaced = np.fromstring( str(buffer), dtype=np.int16 );
        #~ print( "len data: %s " % len( aSoundDataInterlaced ) );
        #~ print( "data interlaced: " ),
        #~ for i in range( 8 ):
            #~ print( "%d, " % (aSoundDataInterlaced[i]) ),
        #~ print( "" );
        aSoundData = np.reshape( aSoundDataInterlaced, (nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel), 'F' );
        #~ print( "len data: %s " % len( aSoundData ) );
        #~ print( "len data 0: %s " % len( aSoundData[0] ) );
        if( False ):
            # compute average
            aAvgValue = np.mean( aSoundData, axis = 1 );
            print( "avg: %s" % aAvgValue );
        if( False ):
            # compute fft
            nBlockSize = nbrOfSamplesByChannel;
            signal = aSoundData[0] * np.hanning( nBlockSize );
            aFft = ( np.fft.rfft(signal) / nBlockSize );
            print aFft;
        if( False ):
            # compute peak
            aPeakValue = np.max( aSoundData );
            if( aPeakValue > 16000 ):
                print( "Peak: %s" % aPeakValue );
        if( True ):
            bSaveAll = True;
            # save to file
            if( self.outfile == None ):
                strFilenameOut = "/out.raw";
                print( "INF: Writing sound to '%s'" % strFilenameOut );
                self.outfile = open( strFilenameOut, "wb" );
                if( bSaveAll ):
                    for nNumChannel in range( 1, nbOfChannels ):
                        strFilenameOutChan = strFilenameOut.replace(".raw", "_%d.raw"%nNumChannel);
                        self.aOutfile[nNumChannel-1] = open( strFilenameOutChan, "wb" );
                        print( "INF: Writing other channel sound to '%s'" % strFilenameOutChan );

            #~ aSoundDataInterlaced.tofile( self.outfile ); # wrote the 4 channels
            aSoundData[0].tofile( self.outfile ); # wrote only one channel
            #~ print( "aTimeStamp: %s" % aTimeStamp );
            #~ print( "data wrotten: " ),
            #~ for i in range( 8 ):
                #~ print( "%d, " % (aSoundData[0][i]) ),
            #~ print( "" );            
            #~ self.stop(); # make naoqi crashes
            if( bSaveAll ):
                for nNumChannel in range( 1, nbOfChannels ):
                    aSoundData[nNumChannel].tofile( self.aOutfile[nNumChannel-1] ); 


    # processRemote - end


    def version( self ):
        return "0.6";

# SoundReceiver - end


def main():
    """ Main entry point

    """
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("--pip",
        help="Parent broker port. The IP address or your robot",
        dest="pip")
    parser.add_option("--pport",
        help="Parent broker port. The port NAOqi is listening to",
        dest="pport",
        type="int")
    parser.set_defaults(
        pip=NAO_IP,
        pport=9559)

    (opts, args_) = parser.parse_args()
    pip   = opts.pip
    pport = opts.pport

    # We need this broker to be able to construct
    # NAOqi modules and subscribe to other modules
    # The broker must stay alive until the program exists
    myBroker = naoqi.ALBroker("myBroker",
       "0.0.0.0",   # listen to anyone
       0,           # find a free port and use it
       pip,         # parent broker IP
       pport)       # parent broker port


    # Warning: SoundReceiver must be a global variable
    # The name given to the constructor must be the name of the
    # variable
    global SoundReceiver
    SoundReceiver = SoundReceiverModule("SoundReceiver", pip)
    SoundReceiver.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print
        print "Interrupted by user, shutting down"
        myBroker.shutdown()
        sys.exit(0)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: How are you sending your audio? I am trying to use an arecord process to stream the audio from the Nao, but I don't know if what is going out is actually correct. I get no response/acknowledgement from the receiver.

Comment: The above code "asks" NAO to send me some buffers thru some ALAudioDevice callbacks and receive and paste those chunks. You don't need something more than that.