# Unable to transcode from audio/l16;rate=48000;channel=1 to one of: audio/x-float-array; rate=16000; channels=1,

Tags: ibm-watson, nao-robot, pepper

I am currently working on Softbanks' robot Pepper and I try to use Watson speech-to-text solution on Pepper's audio buffers remote streaming by using websocket protocol.

I used the answer to that former question [NAO robot remote audio problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243757/nao-robot-remote-audio-problems/24699052#24699052) to find a way to access remotly pepper's audio buffers and that project https://github.com/ibm-dev/watson-streaming-stt to learn how to use websocket protocole to use watson streaming stt.

However, after I open my websocket application, I start sending buffers to watson and after a few sendings, I receive error: 'Unable to transcode from audio/l16;rate=48000;channel=1 to one of: audio/x-float-array; rate=16000; channels=1'

Each time I'm trying to send Pepper's audio buffer to watson, it is unable to understand it.

I compared data I send with data sent in watson streaming stt example (using pyaudio streaming from microphone instead of Pepper's buffer streaming) and I don't see any difference. Both time I'm pretty sure that I am sending a string containing raw chunks of bytes. Which is what Watson asks for in it documentation.

I try to send chunks of 8192 bytes with a sample rate of 48kHz and I can easily convert Pepper's audio buffer in hexa so I don't understand why Watson can't transcode it.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import base64
import configparser
import json
import threading
import time
from optparse import OptionParser
import naoqi
import numpy as np
import sys
from threading import Thread
import ssl

import websocket
from websocket._abnf import ABNF

CHANNELS = 1

NAO_IP = "172.20.10.12" 

class SoundReceiverModule(naoqi.ALModule):
    """
    Use this object to get call back from the ALMemory of the naoqi world.
    Your callback needs to be a method with two parameter (variable name, value).
    """

    def __init__( self, strModuleName, strNaoIp):
        try:
            naoqi.ALModule.__init__(self, strModuleName );
            self.BIND_PYTHON( self.getName(),"callback" );
            self.strNaoIp = strNaoIp;
            self.outfile = None;
            self.aOutfile = [None]*(4-1); # ASSUME max nbr channels = 4
            self.FINALS = []
            self.RECORD_SECONDS = 20
            self.ws_open = False
            self.ws_listening = ""

            # init data for websocket interfaces
            self.headers = {}
            self.userpass = "" #userpass and password
            self.headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + base64.b64encode(
                self.userpass.encode()).decode()
            self.url = ("wss://stream.watsonplatform.net//speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"
                   "?model=fr-FR_BroadbandModel")

        except BaseException, err:
            print( "ERR: abcdk.naoqitools.SoundReceiverModule: loading error: %s" % str(err) );

    # __init__ - end
    def __del__( self ):
        print( "INF: abcdk.SoundReceiverModule.__del__: cleaning everything" );
        self.stop();

    def start( self ):
        audio = naoqi.ALProxy( "ALAudioDevice", self.strNaoIp, 9559 );
        self.nNbrChannelFlag = 3; # ALL_Channels: 0,  AL::LEFTCHANNEL: 1, AL::RIGHTCHANNEL: 2; AL::FRONTCHANNEL: 3  or AL::REARCHANNEL: 4.
        self.nDeinterleave = 0;
        self.nSampleRate = 48000;
        audio.setClientPreferences( self.getName(),  self.nSampleRate, self.nNbrChannelFlag, self.nDeinterleave ); # setting same as default generate a bug !?!
        audio.subscribe( self.getName() );

        #openning websocket app
        self._ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self.url,
                                header=self.headers,
                                on_open = self.on_open,
                                on_message=self.on_message,
                                on_error=self.on_error,
                                on_close=self.on_close) 


        sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE}
        threading.Thread(target=self._ws.run_forever, kwargs = {'sslopt':sslopt}).start()

        print( "INF: SoundReceiver: started!" );

    def stop( self ):
        print( "INF: SoundReceiver: stopping..." );
        audio = naoqi.ALProxy( "ALAudioDevice", self.strNaoIp, 9559 );
        audio.unsubscribe( self.getName() );  
        print( "INF: SoundReceiver: stopped!" );

        print "INF: WebSocket: closing..."
        data = {"action": "stop"}
        self._ws.send(json.dumps(data).encode('utf8'))
        # ... which we need to wait for before we shutdown the websocket
        time.sleep(1)
        self._ws.close()
        print "INF: WebSocket: closed"

        if( self.outfile != None ):
            self.outfile.close();

    def processRemote( self, nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel, aTimeStamp, buffer ):
        """
        This is THE method that receives all the sound buffers from the "ALAudioDevice" module"""

        print "receiving buffer"

        # self.data_to_send = self.data_to_send + buffer

        # print len(self.data_to_send)
        #self.data_to_send = ''.join( [ "%02X " % ord( x ) for x in buffer ] ).strip()
        self.data_to_send = buffer

        #print("buffer type :", type(data))
        #print("buffer :", buffer)
        #~ print( "process!" ); 
        print( "processRemote: %s, %s, %s, lendata: %s, data0: %s (0x%x), data1: %s (0x%x)" % (nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel, aTimeStamp, len(buffer), buffer[0],ord(buffer[0]),buffer[1],ord(buffer[1])) );

        if self.ws_open == True and self.ws_listening == True:
            print "sending data"
            self._ws.send(self.data_to_send, ABNF.OPCODE_BINARY)
            print "data sent"
            #print self.data_to_send

        aSoundDataInterlaced = np.fromstring( str(buffer), dtype=np.int16 );
#        
        aSoundData = np.reshape( aSoundDataInterlaced, (nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel), 'F' );


        # print "processRemote over"
    # processRemote - end

    def on_message(self, ws, msg):

        print("message")
        data = json.loads(msg)
        print data
        if "state" in data:
            if data["state"] == "listening":
                self.ws_listening = True


        if "results" in data:
            if data["results"][0]["final"]:
                self.FINALS.append(data)
            # This prints out the current fragment that we are working on
            print(data['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])


    def on_error(self, ws, error):
        """Print any errors."""
        print(error)


    def on_close(self, ws):
        """Upon close, print the complete and final transcript."""
        transcript = "".join([x['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
                              for x in self.FINALS])
        print("transcript :", transcript)
        self.ws_open = False


    def on_open(self, ws): 
        """Triggered as soon a we have an active connection."""
#        args = self._ws.args

        print "INF: WebSocket: opening"
        data = {
            "action": "start",
            # this means we get to send it straight raw sampling
            "content-type": "audio/l16;rate=%d;channel=1" % self.nSampleRate,
            "continuous": True,
            "interim_results": True,
            # "inactivity_timeout": 5, # in order to use this effectively
            # you need other tests to handle what happens if the socket is
            # closed by the server.
            "word_confidence": True,
            "timestamps": True,
            "max_alternatives": 3
        }

        # Send the initial control message which sets expectations for the
        # binary stream that follows:
        self._ws.send(json.dumps(data).encode('utf8'))
        # Spin off a dedicated thread where we are going to read and
        # stream out audio.

        print "INF: WebSocket: opened"
        self.ws_open = True


    def version( self ):
        return "0.6";

def main():

    """initialisation 
    """
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("--pip",
        help="Parent broker port. The IP address or your robot",
        dest="pip")
    parser.add_option("--pport",
        help="Parent broker port. The port NAOqi is listening to",
        dest="pport",
        type="int")
    parser.set_defaults(
        pip=NAO_IP,
        pport=9559)

    (opts, args_) = parser.parse_args()
    pip   = opts.pip
    pport = opts.pport

    # We need this broker to be able to construct
    # NAOqi modules and subscribe to other modules
    # The broker must stay alive until the program exists
    myBroker = naoqi.ALBroker("myBroker",
       "0.0.0.0",   # listen to anyone
       0,           # find a free port and use it
       pip,         # parent broker IP
       pport)       # parent broker port  


    """fin initialisation 
    """

    global SoundReceiver
    SoundReceiver = SoundReceiverModule("SoundReceiver", pip) #thread1
    SoundReceiver.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print "hello"
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Interrupted by user, shutting down"
        myBroker.shutdown()
        SoundReceiver.stop()
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I would be thankful if anyone had any idea on how to bypass that error or on what to try to get useful info. I first believed that I was sending "wrong" data to watson however after lots of attempts I have no clue on how to fix that problem.

Thank you a lot,

Alex

Comment: Isn't the main problem that you send 48KHz while Watson API requires 16khz ?

Comment: @JLS I don't think the error is due to the sample rate, when I try to do the same thing using pyAudio on my computer (https://github.com/ibm-dev/watson-streaming-stt), I set my sample rate to 48khz as well and it works perfectly. Whereas it still doesn't work when I set Pepper's samplerate to 16kHz haha

Comment: Reading at the error it looks like it says you're sending 16bits sample data and it's waiting for float (eg 32bits float)...

Comment: @AlexandreChenu I know this doesn't answer your question but did you try using the Python SDK? There is an example you can use https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/speaker_text_to_speech.py. Make sure you connect the right buffer.