# Troubles performing remote audio processing with NAO

Tags: python, nao-robot

I am trying to perform some remote audio processing with a NAO v4 using the version 2.1.4.13 of the python naoqi SDK, and I am having difficulties doing so. I have tried using the solution provided by Alexandre Mazel at [NAO robot remote audio problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243757/nao-robot-remote-audio-problems), but I am still having issues retrieving audio data from the buffer. The code referenced in the post is available below. I have also followed the instructions for remotely processing audio data found at https://www.generationrobots.com/media/NAO%20Next%20Gen/FeaturePaper(AudioSignalProcessing)%20(1).pdf

I would greatly appreciate any help or solutions, as I have been stuck on this problem for several days now.

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

###########################################################
# Retrieve robot audio buffer
# Syntaxe:
#    python scriptname --pip <ip> --pport <port>
# 
#    --pip <ip>: specify the ip of your robot (without specification it will use the NAO_IP defined some line below
#
# Author: Alexandre Mazel
###########################################################

NAO_IP = "10.0.252.126" # Romeo on table
#~ NAO_IP = "10.0.253.99" # Nao Alex Blue


from optparse import OptionParser
import naoqi
import numpy as np
import time
import sys


class SoundReceiverModule(naoqi.ALModule):
    """
    Use this object to get call back from the ALMemory of the naoqi world.
    Your callback needs to be a method with two parameter (variable name, value).
    """

    def __init__( self, strModuleName, strNaoIp ):
        try:
            naoqi.ALModule.__init__(self, strModuleName );
            self.BIND_PYTHON( self.getName(),"callback" );
            self.strNaoIp = strNaoIp;
            self.outfile = None;
            self.aOutfile = [None]*(4-1); # ASSUME max nbr channels = 4
        except BaseException, err:
            print( "ERR: abcdk.naoqitools.SoundReceiverModule: loading error: %s" % str(err) );

    # __init__ - end
    def __del__( self ):
        print( "INF: abcdk.SoundReceiverModule.__del__: cleaning everything" );
        self.stop();

    def start( self ):
        audio = naoqi.ALProxy( "ALAudioDevice", self.strNaoIp, 9559 );
        nNbrChannelFlag = 0; # ALL_Channels: 0,  AL::LEFTCHANNEL: 1, AL::RIGHTCHANNEL: 2; AL::FRONTCHANNEL: 3  or AL::REARCHANNEL: 4.
        nDeinterleave = 0;
        nSampleRate = 48000;
        audio.setClientPreferences( self.getName(),  nSampleRate, nNbrChannelFlag, nDeinterleave ); # setting same as default generate a bug !?!
        audio.subscribe( self.getName() );
        print( "INF: SoundReceiver: started!" );
        # self.processRemote( 4, 128, [18,0], "A"*128*4*2 ); # for local test

        # on romeo, here's the current order:
        # 0: right;  1: rear;   2: left;   3: front,  

    def stop( self ):
        print( "INF: SoundReceiver: stopping..." );
        audio = naoqi.ALProxy( "ALAudioDevice", self.strNaoIp, 9559 );
        audio.unsubscribe( self.getName() );        
        print( "INF: SoundReceiver: stopped!" );
        if( self.outfile != None ):
            self.outfile.close();


    def processRemote( self, nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel, aTimeStamp, buffer ):
        """
        This is THE method that receives all the sound buffers from the "ALAudioDevice" module
        """
        #~ print( "process!" );
        #~ print( "processRemote: %s, %s, %s, lendata: %s, data0: %s (0x%x), data1: %s (0x%x)" % (nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel, aTimeStamp, len(buffer), buffer[0],ord(buffer[0]),buffer[1],ord(buffer[1])) );
        #~ print( "raw data: " ),
        #~ for i in range( 8 ):
            #~ print( "%s (0x%x), " % (buffer[i],ord(buffer[i])) ),
        #~ print( "" );

        aSoundDataInterlaced = np.fromstring( str(buffer), dtype=np.int16 );
        #~ print( "len data: %s " % len( aSoundDataInterlaced ) );
        #~ print( "data interlaced: " ),
        #~ for i in range( 8 ):
            #~ print( "%d, " % (aSoundDataInterlaced[i]) ),
        #~ print( "" );
        aSoundData = np.reshape( aSoundDataInterlaced, (nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel), 'F' );
        #~ print( "len data: %s " % len( aSoundData ) );
        #~ print( "len data 0: %s " % len( aSoundData[0] ) );
        if( False ):
            # compute average
            aAvgValue = np.mean( aSoundData, axis = 1 );
            print( "avg: %s" % aAvgValue );
        if( False ):
            # compute fft
            nBlockSize = nbrOfSamplesByChannel;
            signal = aSoundData[0] * np.hanning( nBlockSize );
            aFft = ( np.fft.rfft(signal) / nBlockSize );
            print aFft;
        if( False ):
            # compute peak
            aPeakValue = np.max( aSoundData );
            if( aPeakValue > 16000 ):
                print( "Peak: %s" % aPeakValue );
        if( True ):
            bSaveAll = True;
            # save to file
            if( self.outfile == None ):
                strFilenameOut = "/out.raw";
                print( "INF: Writing sound to '%s'" % strFilenameOut );
                self.outfile = open( strFilenameOut, "wb" );
                if( bSaveAll ):
                    for nNumChannel in range( 1, nbOfChannels ):
                        strFilenameOutChan = strFilenameOut.replace(".raw", "_%d.raw"%nNumChannel);
                        self.aOutfile[nNumChannel-1] = open( strFilenameOutChan, "wb" );
                        print( "INF: Writing other channel sound to '%s'" % strFilenameOutChan );

            #~ aSoundDataInterlaced.tofile( self.outfile ); # wrote the 4 channels
            aSoundData[0].tofile( self.outfile ); # wrote only one channel
            #~ print( "aTimeStamp: %s" % aTimeStamp );
            #~ print( "data wrotten: " ),
            #~ for i in range( 8 ):
                #~ print( "%d, " % (aSoundData[0][i]) ),
            #~ print( "" );            
            #~ self.stop(); # make naoqi crashes
            if( bSaveAll ):
                for nNumChannel in range( 1, nbOfChannels ):
                    aSoundData[nNumChannel].tofile( self.aOutfile[nNumChannel-1] ); 


    # processRemote - end


    def version( self ):
        return "0.6";

# SoundReceiver - end


def main():
    """ Main entry point

    """
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("--pip",
        help="Parent broker port. The IP address or your robot",
        dest="pip")
    parser.add_option("--pport",
        help="Parent broker port. The port NAOqi is listening to",
        dest="pport",
        type="int")
    parser.set_defaults(
        pip=NAO_IP,
        pport=9559)

    (opts, args_) = parser.parse_args()
    pip   = opts.pip
    pport = opts.pport

    # We need this broker to be able to construct
    # NAOqi modules and subscribe to other modules
    # The broker must stay alive until the program exists
    myBroker = naoqi.ALBroker("myBroker",
       "0.0.0.0",   # listen to anyone
       0,           # find a free port and use it
       pip,         # parent broker IP
       pport)       # parent broker port


    # Warning: SoundReceiver must be a global variable
    # The name given to the constructor must be the name of the
    # variable
    global SoundReceiver
    SoundReceiver = SoundReceiverModule("SoundReceiver", pip)
    SoundReceiver.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print
        print "Interrupted by user, shutting down"
        myBroker.shutdown()
        sys.exit(0)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: "but I am still having issues retrieving audio data from the buffer." Is an error being thrown? Is the buffer empty? Can you access the buffer? What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Hi Andrew, no error is being thrown. According to the NAOqi documentation, the module ALAudioDevice is supposed to send audio data to the buffer through the processRemote function. However, it doesn't seem to be passing that data to function. I can tell because when I try to convert the raw data to a wav file, the resulting wav file is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Maybe this project can help you as orientation:

  https://github.com/UNSWComputing/rUNSWift-2015-release/wiki/Whistle-Detection

  It offers a `whistle_detector.py` Python module that

  > also runs on the Nao under the 2.1 toolchain / Nao V4.
- Also this project is worth a visit:

  https://www.ibm.com/blogs/watson/2016/07/getting-robots-listen-using-watsons-speech-text-service/

  It uses an approach by calling the linux command `arecord` instead of using `ALAudioDevice`

Comment: Thank you very much. This should be enough to get me pointed in the right direction. I want to note that I am using Windows OS, so is there anything similar to arecord for Windows?

Comment: Welcome! The script from the second project is executed on the robot where linux runs. Therefore the command "arecord" is also executed on the robot linux. The OS of your development device is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the example from the [documentation](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/python/examples/audio/audio_soundprocessing.html)?

Try to run this on the robot:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: UTF-8 -*-

"""Example: Get Signal from Front Microphone & Calculate its rms Power"""


import qi
import argparse
import sys
import time
import numpy as np


class SoundProcessingModule(object):
    """
    A simple get signal from the front microphone of Nao & calculate its rms power.
    It requires numpy.
    """

    def __init__( self, app):
        """
        Initialise services and variables.
        """
        super(SoundProcessingModule, self).__init__()
        app.start()
        session = app.session

        # Get the service ALAudioDevice.
        self.audio_service = session.service("ALAudioDevice")
        self.isProcessingDone = False
        self.nbOfFramesToProcess = 20
        self.framesCount=0
        self.micFront = []
        self.module_name = "SoundProcessingModule"

    def startProcessing(self):
        """
        Start processing
        """
        # ask for the front microphone signal sampled at 16kHz
        # if you want the 4 channels call setClientPreferences(self.module_name, 48000, 0, 0)
        self.audio_service.setClientPreferences(self.module_name, 16000, 3, 0)
        self.audio_service.subscribe(self.module_name)

        while self.isProcessingDone == False:
            time.sleep(1)

        self.audio_service.unsubscribe(self.module_name)

    def processRemote(self, nbOfChannels, nbOfSamplesByChannel, timeStamp, inputBuffer):
        """
        Compute RMS from mic.
        """
        self.framesCount = self.framesCount + 1

        if (self.framesCount <= self.nbOfFramesToProcess):
            # convert inputBuffer to signed integer as it is interpreted as a string by python
            self.micFront=self.convertStr2SignedInt(inputBuffer)
            #compute the rms level on front mic
            rmsMicFront = self.calcRMSLevel(self.micFront)
            print "rms level mic front = " + str(rmsMicFront)
        else :
            self.isProcessingDone=True

    def calcRMSLevel(self,data) :
        """
        Calculate RMS level
        """
        rms = 20 * np.log10( np.sqrt( np.sum( np.power(data,2) / len(data)  )))
        return rms

    def convertStr2SignedInt(self, data) :
        """
        This function takes a string containing 16 bits little endian sound
        samples as input and returns a vector containing the 16 bits sound
        samples values converted between -1 and 1.
        """
        signedData=[]
        ind=0;
        for i in range (0,len(data)/2) :
            signedData.append(data[ind]+data[ind+1]*256)
            ind=ind+2

        for i in range (0,len(signedData)) :
            if signedData[i]>=32768 :
                signedData[i]=signedData[i]-65536

        for i in range (0,len(signedData)) :
            signedData[i]=signedData[i]/32768.0

        return signedData


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--ip", type=str, default="127.0.0.1",
                        help="Robot IP address. On robot or Local Naoqi: use '127.0.0.1'.")
    parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=9559,
                        help="Naoqi port number")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    try:
        # Initialize qi framework.
        connection_url = "tcp://" + args.ip + ":" + str(args.port)
        app = qi.Application(["SoundProcessingModule", "--qi-url=" + connection_url])
    except RuntimeError:
        print ("Can't connect to Naoqi at ip \"" + args.ip + "\" on port " + str(args.port) +".\n"
               "Please check your script arguments. Run with -h option for help.")
        sys.exit(1)
    MySoundProcessingModule = SoundProcessingModule(app)
    app.session.registerService("SoundProcessingModule", MySoundProcessingModule)
    MySoundProcessingModule.startProcessing()
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried using this example. However, it does not work as I am using an older version of the python naoqi SDK that is compatible with the NAO robot I am using