# NAO Robot: How to rewrite the sound processing example for qi framework?

Tags: nao-robot

Could anybody help me rewriting the following sound processing example in qi framework in C++?

http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/dev/cpp/examples/audio/soundprocessing/soundprocessing.html

I am aware of an example in Python, but it does not help me much with C++. The original example uses a class that derives from ALSoundExtractor and declares function process() which overrides a virtual function from ALSoundExtractor. It behaves like a callback function and it works for me in the older NAOqi 2.1.4.

Alternatively, if overriding the process() function is not appropriate in qi framework anymore, I would be interested in any other way of accessing the audio data.

Comment: Do you have any piece of code already, and something that blocks you precisely?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NAO robot: porting ALSoundExtractor to qi framwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63232083/nao-robot-porting-alsoundextractor-to-qi-framwork)

Comment: I will test the code you have posted in the other thread. That's definitely a new piece of code compared to what I had so far. I will then replay in the other thread.