# NAO robot audio streaming to PC using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyaudio

i'm looking for a way to stream NAO microphone/s audio to my python app.
Closest i found was there: [NAO robot remote audio problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243757/nao-robot-remote-audio-problems). I removed the file saving and added audio stream + set only 1 channel for now:

```
    def start(self):
        audio = naoqi.ALProxy("ALAudioDevice", self.strNaoIp, 9559)
        nNbrChannelFlag = 3  # ALL_Channels: 0,  AL::LEFTCHANNEL: 1, AL::RIGHTCHANNEL: 2; AL::FRONTCHANNEL: 3  or AL::REARCHANNEL: 4.
        nDeinterleave = 0
        nSampleRate = 16000
        audio.setClientPreferences(self.getName(), nSampleRate, nNbrChannelFlag,
                                   nDeinterleave)  # setting same as default generate a bug !?!
        audio.subscribe(self.getName())
        print("INF: SoundReceiver: started!")

def processRemote(self, nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel, aTimeStamp, buffer_audio):
        """
        This is THE method that receives all the sound buffers from the "ALAudioDevice" module
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243757/nao-robot-remote-audio-problems
        """
        aSoundDataInterlaced = np.fromstring(str(buffer_audio), dtype=np.int16)

        aSoundData = np.reshape(aSoundDataInterlaced, (nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel), 'F')
        # print "input data:", aSoundDataInterlaced
        # print "Processed data:", aSoundData

        if (True):
            # compute peak
            aPeakValue = np.max(aSoundData)
            if (aPeakValue > 16000):
                print("Peak: %s" % aPeakValue)

            p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

            def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
                return (buffer_audio, pyaudio.paContinue)
                # return (aSoundDataInterlaced, pyaudio.paContinue)
            print nbOfChannels
            print nbrOfSamplesByChannel
            print aTimeStamp

            stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(1),
                            channels=nbOfChannels,
                            rate=nbrOfSamplesByChannel,
                            output=True,
                            stream_callback=callback)
            # stream.write(aSoundData[0])
            stream.start_stream()
```

However when i launch it the sound is similiar to metro coming to a station (air moving). When i try to print out value of sampling frequency (nbrOfSamplesByChannel) it prints out 1365. Isn't it supposed to be 16000 same as sampling frequency?
According to softbank info it is supposed to have 170ms buffer but i don't know how to work with that or if it is relevant (http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/audio/alaudiodevice.html#alaudiodevice)

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

16000Hz is the number of samples per second / sampling frequency. It is the number of samples per second. One buffer that is received by the callback function is 1365 samples. So between the arriving buffers 1365 samples * 1 / (16000 samples / second) = 0.0853125 second should pass. So each 85.3 ms (roughly) there should be a new buffer arriving containing the samples since the last call of the function. And keep in mind that each audio sample is encoded using 16 bits, so if you just print the length of the buffer, you will probably get 1365 * 2 = 2730, because Python2 gives you the length in bytes.

Here are some resources that may be helpful:

- https://www.generationrobots.com/media/NAO%20Next%20Gen/FeaturePaper(AudioSignalProcessing)%20(1).pdf
- http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/dev/python/examples/audio/audio_soundprocessing.html
- http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/ref/libalaudio/alsoundextractor_8h.html # here it is described which channel corresponds to the parameters 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
- https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1729881417714996

You can also have a look at our project that integrates GPT4 with NAO: https://github.com/TarzanOfTheOcean/nao_meets_gpt4_v4

Best regards!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).